# FireDac get the count of rows affected by FDQuery.execsql command

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

How we can get the count of affected by `FDQuery.ExecSQL` command of FireDAC after execution of INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE commands on table1 of SQLITE database?

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text:='UPDATE table1 SET col1='abc' WHERE id<100';
FDQuery.ExecSQL;
```

How we can get the number of affected rows ?

The same query in ADO returns from MSSQL database the number of affected rows.

```
AffectedCount:=ADOQuery.ExecSQL;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of ways.

---

```
n := FDConnection1.ExecSQL('UPDATE table1 SET col1=''abc'' WHERE id<100');
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Executing_Commands_(FireDAC)
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.ExecSQL

Executes a SQL command and returns the number of affected rows.

---

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text:='UPDATE table1 SET col1=''abc'' WHERE id<100';
FDQuery.ExecSQL;
n := FDQuery.RowsAffected;
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Executing_Commands_(FireDAC)
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDRdbmsDataSet.RowsAffected

Getting DBMS Feedback

Use the TFDQuery.RowsAffected property to get the number of rows processed by the command (for example, the number of deleted rows by the DELETE command.) 
Note: For MS SQL Server, RowsAffected can be unexpectedly equal to -1 when a stored procedure or a table trigger omits SET NOCOUNT ON. Then, use the TFDQuery.RecordCount property to get the number of fetched rows.

---

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text:='UPDATE table1 SET col1=''abc'' WHERE id<100';
FDQuery.ExecSQL;
FDQuery.SQL.Text:='SELECT changes()';
FDQuery.Open;
n := FDQuery.Fields[0].AsInteger;
```

---

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle//en/Data.DB.TDataSet.PSExecuteStatement

PSExecuteStatement returns the number of rows affected by executing ASQL.

I do not know if AnyDAC implements this though.

Comment: `MS SQL Server, RowsAffected can be unexpectedly equal to -1 .... SET NOCOUNT ON` ping back from 2023. I spent few days trying to graso why one `ADOQuery` based kegacy app stopped working, and i even when that far to patch RTL to re-implement `RowsAffected`...  Today i found i already wrote about this 7 years ago...